# Remove rows from SQL DB that appear in a Array

Tags: c++, sql, arrays, mfc

I Develop with MFC Visual C++ and Oracle SQL Server.
I have SQL table with: IDs, value and time, when the application insert a new row: some ID, some Value and time being inserted.

My goal is to delete rows of values that were changed between certain time. since the data that was inserted during that time has incorrect value.

Where is the catch ? I dont need to delete all the rows that were updated in that time period, only the rows with IDs that appear on a certain CArray.

I can go through each ID from CArray and execute a delete query to that certain ID in that time period (whether there is entry or not) - problem since i can have 150K IDs to iterate 
on..

Thanks

Comment: Is the ID the primary key? If so, you can just delete anything with the ID and totally ignore when they were added since each ID should be unique.

Comment: ID is not primary key, there is no primary key in that table. I can use CRecordSet to poll the rows

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table-name WHERE id in (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

transform your array into a tempTable with one column and then delete from your destiantion table where ID in (select Id from temptable)

Here is an example:

```
declare @RegionID varchar(50)
SET @RegionID = '853,834,16,467,841'
declare @S varchar(20)
if LEN(@RegionID) > 0 SET @RegionID = @RegionID + ',' 
CREATE TABLE #ARRAY(region_ID VARCHAR(20))

WHILE LEN(@RegionID) > 0 BEGIN
   SELECT @S = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RegionID, 1, CHARINDEX(',', @RegionID) - 1))
   INSERT INTO #ARRAY (region_ID) VALUES (@S)
   SELECT @RegionID = SUBSTRING(@RegionID, CHARINDEX(',', @RegionID) + 1, LEN(@RegionID))
END

delete from from your_table
where regionID IN (select region_ID from #ARRAY)
```

Comment: When i make a table from code, If i insert rows to the table, it takes something like 1 minutes for each 20K rows, maybe DB limitation, so to load the CArray with 150K gonna take too long